# Remove/ hide table row if all columns are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been trying to hide the complete table row in case all the tds are empty . I works fine but in case any td has blank space the code doesn't work for that tr.

Following is the code snippet

```js
$('tr').filter(
    function(){
        return $(this).find('td').length == $(this).find('td:empty').length;
    }).hide();
```

```css
table {
    empty-cells: show;
}

td {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
         <tr >
            <td>a</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TjfPa/210/)

Please help .. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `filter()` the TDs  and use `trim()` to avoid white-spaces .. like so

```
$('tr').filter(
    function(){
        return $(this).find('td').length == $(this).find('td').filter(function(){
            return $(this).text().trim() == '';
        }).length;
    }).hide();


   $("tr").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "-";
}).parent().hide();
```

> Note: be sure to use `find('td')` instead of `find('td:empty')`

```js
$('tr').filter(
    function(){
        return $(this).find('td').length == $(this).find('td').filter(function(){
         return $(this).text().trim() == '';
        }).length;
    }).hide();
    
   
   $("tr").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "-";
}).parent().hide();
```

```css
table {
    empty-cells: show;
}

td {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
         <tr >
            <td>a</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @user3852040 You're totally welcome .. Have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change `.length` to `.text().trim().length` so that you're checking the length of the text within the elements, trimmed of any white space:

`return $(this).find('td').text().trim().length === 0;`

Your code is checking to see how many TDs exist in a row, not whether they're empty. The line above checks to see if there's any non-whitespace.

`.trim()` removes all whitespace, including new lines and `&nbsp;`.

See the jQuery docs on `.text()` and `.trim()`:

- http://api.jquery.com/text/
- https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Answer (score 0):

1. Use like this [`Array#each`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj0_8XxsLfTAhUFQ48KHWHpBX8QFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FforEach&usg=AFQjCNFWWfwOQKjXdfPWyAU9FxufcTqwMg&sig2=VNL9zM2y3ahFdtrjZLc4AA) function
2. And apply [`trim()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjEp6zosLfTAhXFtY8KHayCAdwQFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_trim_string.asp&usg=AFQjCNEDh_x7JMeCVu0sakhKLDvxAVHYaw&sig2=EaGbMTI2Cy0h5_KNkA_Nzg) .It will ignore the `&npsb` spaces .
3. Finally used with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every?v=example)

***Explanation***

- First Iterate then each `tr` tag and then itearete the each `'td'` tag children of `tr`.
- Then validate the each `td` its have some content or empty.
- its a empty add `1` inside the array.else pass `0`
- Then check the array all are same `arguments` or not
- Finally applied the `hide` and `show` function

```js
$('tr').each(function() {
  var n = [];
 $(this).children('td').each(a => n.push(($(this).text().trim() == "") ? 1 : 0))
  n.every(a => a) ? $(this).hide() : $(this).show();
})
```

```css
table {
  empty-cells: show;
}

td {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```